# Obsoleted CAS trying to compile a class

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am getting the following error trying to open a DevExpress report in VS 2010.

> This method explicitly uses CAS
>   policy, which has been obsoleted by
>   the .NET Framework. In order to enable
>   CAS policy for compatibility reasons,
>   please use the
>   NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy
>   configuration switch. Please see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570
>   for more information.

The project is set to framework 3.5, but when I go to the link provided, the first sentence reads:

> The policy portion of code access
>   security (CAS) has been made obsolete
>   in the .NET Framework version 4

I have no apparent connection to framework v4, so I'm a bit stumped as to what is causing this.  How can I go into a deeper diagnosis of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 itself uses .NET 4.0 even if your project targets a different framework version.  It sounds like something in the DevExpress report designer or code that it invokes might be using CAS policy.  Which version of which DevExpress product are you using?

Comment: I'm using 8.3, I can't go higher because we only have a license for 8.3.

Comment: DevExpress only supports 10.1 and higher for use with VS 2010.  If you want proper designer support, you'll either need to upgrade DevExpress or use VS 2008.  If neither of these is an option, you should pretty much expect to encounter a variety of design-time issues.

Comment: BTW, you may be able to work around this particular problem by adding the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409253.aspx) element to your VS 2010 config file (Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config in your VS 2010 directory).